# How to get the innerHTML of a division with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I currently have the following setup for an editable-content field

```
const Input = () => {

    const Enter = () => { ... }

    const Editable = () => (
        <div className={"editable"} contentEditable={"true"}>
            This is some text
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <div>
            <Editable />
            <Enter />
        </ div>
    )

}
```

This is how this renders,  `<Enter />` is the button that reads "send".

[image]

As the user enters more text into the field that currently reads "This is some text" the `<div>` with `className={"input"}` gets some html added to it. For example, if I enter the following text:

```
This is some text (line 0)
This is some more text (line 1)
This is even more text (line 2)
This is the final line (line 4)
```

The inner HTML for this `<div>` is

```html
<div class="editable" contentEditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
    <div>This is some text (line 0)</div>
    <div>This is some more text (line 1)</div>
    <div>This is even more text (line 2)</div>
    <div>This is the final line (line 4)</div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to get the inner HTML of this `<div>`, as plain text or otherwise.
How can I do this using React?

Many thanks - Oli

Comment: How is this div able to accept input?

Comment: @JulianKleine `contentEditable={"true"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by assigning an id to your `editableContent` div and using `document.getElementById`. Check this sandbox to see how I implemented it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-neumann-u0uqz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark